# SQL merge entries with start and end dates to entries with single dates

Tags: sql, date, merge

I have two tables, lets call them A and B. Table A has data regarding specific events and has a unique key column pairing of `event_date` and `person`. Table B has aggregate data over time and thus has key columns `start_date`,`end_date` and `person`. The date ranges in table B will never overlap for a given person so `end_date` is not strictly necessary for the composite key.

Below are two examples

```
SELECT event_date, person
FROM A
```

| event_date | person |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | Alice |
| 2021-10-01 | Bob |
| 2021-10-05 | Bob |
| 2021-11-05 | Bob |

```
SELECT start_date, end_date, person, attribute
FROM B
```

| start_date | end_date | person | attribute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021-11-01 | Alice | Attribute 1 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021-11-01 | Bob | Attribute 1 |
| 2021-11-01 | 2021-12-01 | Bob | Attribute 2 |

I would like to add the `attribute` column to table A. The merger should consider in which date range the `event_date` column falls into and choose the appropriate attribute. The final table after the merge should look like this:

| event_date | person | attribute |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | Alice | Attribute 1 |
| 2021-10-01 | Bob | Attribute 1 |
| 2021-10-05 | Bob | Attribute 1 |
| 2021-11-05 | Bob | Attribute 2 |

How would one go about solving this?

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to `JOIN` by `BETWEEN` dates.

```
SELECT a.*,b.attribute
FROM A a
JOIN B b
ON a.event_date BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.end_date
AND a.person = b.person
```